# Redirects in Apache

Tags: apache, http, redirect

Can anyone help.
Im need to write a redirect rule that :

redirects all HTTPS traffic back to HTTP unless it has the URL /administrator within it.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^administrator/
RewriteRule .? http://www.site2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a condition that checks if it's HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^administrator/
RewriteRule .? http://www.site2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ive just tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @felix001 so what does it do? Works perfectly fine for me in a blank htaccess file and a new apache install.

Comment: Yep sorry this works fine now, the issue was due to the ordering within my .htaccess.